# What are the advantages of testing your Javascript with Jasmine - a BDD approach?

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, jasmine

What are the advantages of using [Jasmine](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine/) to test your Javascript?

How does it differ from traditional testing of JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google it, you can find plenty of articles about BDD and Jasmine. I recently read some good articles about BDD and Jasmine. These will explain what you want to know.

1. Introducing BDD 
   http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/
2. Pragmatic JavaScript Testing with Jasmine http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/07/06/pragmatic-javascript-testing-with-jasmine/

And the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BDD) also has good explanations about BDD.